# how to simply import custom module (file with sql queries)

Tags: airflow

I have some SQL queries I want to store in a file so I can call them easily. The file is named `sql_queries.py` and stored in a `helpers` folder under `plugins` folder.

```
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
import helpers

class SqlQueries:
    songplay_table_insert = ("""
        SELECT *
        FROM XXXX
    """)

class Project(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "Project"
    helpers = [SqlQueries]
```

I'm trying to import my queries from my dag like this `from airflow.helpers import SqlQueries`

I've used the same system for operators and it works. Why it doesn't in this case?

Comment: You can simply create a folder SQL in DAG folder and place your file there. Then import it as from SQL.SQLqueries import * .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need Airflow plugins for this, you can import any custom module in your DAG like a normal Python module.

I would say store `sql_queries.py` in any folder that is on `PYTHONPATH` and contains `__init__.py`

Example:

You can directly place `sql_queries.py` inside DAGs directory and import it as follows in your DAG as the `dags/` directory is already in the PYTHONPATH:

```
import sql_queries
```

Comment: What should I include in my init file in that case?

Comment: `__init__.py` just needs to be a blank file. Having a blank `__init__.py` file inside any folder makes it a package. Check this SO post for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Answer (score 0):

Because Airflow plugins don't support the creation of helpers. You can code custom executors, macros, admin_views, flask_blueprints, menu_links, appbuilder_views, appbuilder_menu_items, global_operator_extra_links and operator_extra_links.

You can have the script as a regular package import or convert that piece of code to a method within a custom Hook.